# Update data in a server component with client components in it

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I started with NextJS 13 two weeks ago. From what I know now, it is impossible to update some parts of a server component from included client components.

My server component, is a shopping list. This component loads the list items server side and a loop inserts client components, the list items. To not just have a static list, I have functions to update the quantity of a list item, the name, delete and some more.

Here is the code a little simplified:
The server component:

```
import ...

import ListItem from '../../../components/listItem';

let showAddNewItemMenu = false;
let showEditItemMenu = false;

const fetchList = async (id) => {
    const response = await fetch('https://next-homanizer.projekt-eleven.eu/api/lists?type=list&id=' + id, {
        'headers': headers()
    });
    const responseData = (await response.json());

    return responseData.data;
}

functions to manipulate the list and its items ...

export default async function Shopping({params}: {params: {listId: string}})
{
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

    if(!session)
        redirect('/auto-login');

    const list = await fetchList(params.listId);

    return (
        <div className="w-full h-full flex flex-col">
            {
                showAddNewItemMenu && (
                    <div className="w-full px-6 pt-2 pb-8 flex flex-col space-y-4">
                        ADD NEW ITEM MENU
                    </div>
                )
            }

            {
                showEditItemMenu && (
                    <div className="w-full px-6 pt-2 pb-8 flex flex-col space-y-4">
                        EDIT MENU
                    </div>
                )
            }

            <div className="w-full h-full flex flex-col overflow-y-auto">
                {
                    list?.items?.map((item, index) => (
                        <ListItem key={index} listId={list.id} listItem={item} />
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The client component for a list item:

```
'use client'

import ...

functions for manipulate items

let showEditMenu = false;

let amountEditTimeout = null;
let longClickTimeout = null;

export default function ListItem({listId, listItem})
{
    return (
        <div className={(showEditMenu ? 'bg-list-item-selected' : 'bg-list-item') + ' w-full px-4 py-2 flex flex-col'}>
            <div className="w-full flex items-center">
                {
                    listItem.done ?
                    (
                        <div
                            className="w-6 h-6 mr-4 flex items-center justify-center shrink-0"
                            onClick={() => {updateItemDoneStatus(listId, listItem)}}
                        >
                            <FontAwesomeIcon
                                icon={faCheck}
                                className="text-button-1 text-lg"
                            />
                        </div>
                    )
                    :
                    (
                        <div
                            className="w-6 h-6 border-2 border-border-2 rounded mr-4 flex items-center justify-center shrink-0"
                            onClick={() => {updateItemDoneStatus(listId, listItem)}}
                        ></div>
                    )
                }

                // item
                <div
                    className="w-full flex flex-col"
                >
                    <div className={(listItem.done ? 'text-text-3 line-through' : 'text-text') + ' w-full text-md'}>{listItem.name}</div>

                    <div className={(listItem.done ? 'text-text-3' : 'text-text-1') + ' w-full text-xs'}>{listItem.amount + ' ' + listItem.unit}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            {
                showEditMenu && (
                    <div
                        className={(listItem.done ? 'text-text-3' : 'text-white') + ' w-full pt-4 pb-2 pl-10 flex'}
                        // @click.outside="showEditMenu = null"
                    >
                        <div className="w-full flex items-center space-x-6">
                            <FontAwesomeIcon
                                icon={faCircleMinus}
                                className="text-xl"
                                onClick={() => updateItemAmount(listId, listItem, -1)}
                            />

                            <FontAwesomeIcon
                                icon={faCirclePlus}
                                className="text-xl"
                                onClick={() => updateItemAmount(listId, listItem, 1)}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="w-full flex items-center justify-end space-x-6">
                            <FontAwesomeIcon
                                icon={faPen}
                                className="text-xl"
                                // @click="openEditItemMenu(item)"
                            />

                            <FontAwesomeIcon
                                icon={faTrash}
                                className={(listItem.done ? 'text-button-2-done' : 'text-button-2') + ' text-xl'}
                                // @click="removeItem(item.id)"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

My questions now are:

1. how can I update the "parent", the server component, when I have changed a list item?
2. is it efficient if I put the functions in the client component or can I trigger function of the server component?
3. how can I display the edit menu of the server component and fill it with the data of the selected list item?
4. i have developed this with AlpineJS, is there an easier way to transfer the code to NextJS?